# WPF Binding property of an Object contained within Another Object contained in a List

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox showing some information about Cars.  So, I have ViewModel with:

```
private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars;
public ObservableCollection<Car> CarsList
{
    get
    {
        return _cars;
    }
    set
    {
        _cars= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CarsList");
    }
}
```

I have implemented PropertyChanged, and I get my list of cars just fine. I load my CarsList from within my ViewModel (not from Window).

My Car object has Name, Country, Url and Image object like below:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I need to bind Name, Country and Image.Url to text boxes in my ListBox.  I did this like:

```
<ListBox Name="lbEvents" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CarsList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Name="txtCarName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Name="txtCarCountry" Text="{Binding Path=Country}"/>
<!-- How do I bind this properly? -->
                    <Image Name="imgCarImage" Source="{Binding Path=Car.Image.Url}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Problem is that my Car Name and Country are properly displayed in ListBox for each Car.  But Car.Image.Url shows nothing.  I am new to WPF, how do I bind properly the Image.Url to the ImageBox?

Comment: Thanks @m-y, that was it.  I cant mark your answer since you posted it as comment.  Post it as answer and I'll mark it as solved.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as `Name` and `Country` are properties of the `Car` class, so is `Image`. Look at the way you are binding to `Name` and `Country`, you don't specify it as `Car.Name`, so why do that for `Image`? Just do it as `Image` instead of `Car.Image`.